# I am getting error because of the trigger event

Tags: apex, trigger, controller

I have a trigger which will call an handler

```java
trigger ASNSeasonalAllocationTrigger on ASN_POS_Item__c (after update) 
{
    FetzerCalculateTotalAllocatedForAUser.calculateQuantityReceived(Trigger.oldMap,Trigger.newMap);
}
```

```java
public static void calculateQuantityReceived(Map<Id, ASN_POS_Item__c> oldASNPOSItem, Map<Id, ASN_POS_Item__c> newASNPOSItem)
{
    System.debug('isnide calculateQuantityReceived---');
    ASN_POS_Item__c asnPosItem = newASNPOSItem.values()[0];
    System.debug('asnPosItem---'+asnPosItem);
    System.debug('asnPosItem.Advance_Shipment_Notice__r.Program__c---'+asnPosItem.Advance_Shipment_Notice__c);
    Advance_Shipment_Notice__c asnDetails = [SELECT Id, Program__c, Facility__c, CreatedById FROM Advance_Shipment_Notice__c WHERE Id = :asnPosItem.Advance_Shipment_Notice__c];
    System.debug('asnDetails---'+asnDetails);
    if(asnDetails.Program__c !=null)
    {
        System.debug('line 34---');
        Decimal oldQuantityReceived = oldASNPOSItem.get(asnPosItem.Id).Quantity_Received__c;

        System.debug('line 37---');
        if(asnPosItem.Quantity_Received__c > 0)
        {
            System.debug('line 40---');
            String asnId = asnPosItem.Advance_Shipment_Notice__c;
            String posItemId = asnPosItem.POS_Item__c;
            String facilityId = asnDetails.Facility__c;
            Integer quantityReceived = 0;
                   
            if(asnPosItem.Quantity_Received__c > asnPosItem.Quantity__c)
            {
                 System.debug('line 48---');
                 Integer quantityDifference = Integer.ValueOf(asnPosItem.Quantity_Received__c) - Integer.ValueOf(asnPosItem.Quantity__c);
                 Integer quantity = Integer.ValueOf(asnPosItem.Quantity__c) ;
                 //Notify the admin with quantity difference with an asn id and quantity difference
                 calculateTotalAllocation(asnId, posItemId, facilityId, quantity);
                         
            }
            else if(asnPosItem.Quantity_Received__c <= asnPosItem.Quantity__c){
                      
                Integer quantity = Integer.ValueOf(asnPosItem.Quantity_Received__c) ;
                calculateTotalAllocation(asnId, posItemId, facilityId, quantity);
                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@AuraEnabled
public Static void calculateTotalAllocation(String asnId,String posItemId,String facilityId,Integer totalASNItemProcessed)
{
    System.debug('posItemId---'+posItemId);
    System.debug('asnId---'+asnId);
    System.debug('facilityId---'+facilityId);
    System.debug('totalASNItemProcessed---'+totalASNItemProcessed);
    objAccount = getAccount_Apex();
    List<Program_Items_Facility_Allocations__c> programItemFacilityAllocationList = [SELECT Id, Program_Item__c, Total_Ordered_Quantity__c, 
                                                    Facility__c, Ratio__c, Total_allocated_quantity__c, Processing_Count__c, Allocations_Remaining__c, User__c FROM Program_Items_Facility_Allocations__c 
                                                    WHERE Facility__c = :facilityId AND Program_Item__r.POS_Item__c = :posItemId AND Processed__c = false ORDER BY 
                                                    CreatedDate ASC];
        
       
    ASN_POS_Item__c asnPosItem = [SELECT Id, POS_Item__c, Quantity_Received__c FROM ASN_POS_Item__c WHERE POS_Item__c = :posItemId AND Advance_Shipment_Notice__c = :asnId  ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
    System.debug('programItemFacilityAllocationList----'+programItemFacilityAllocationList);
    //System.debug('asnPosItem----'+asnPosItem);
    List<Processing_Date_and_Time__c> processingDateList = new List<Processing_Date_and_Time__c>();
    List<Program_Items_Facility_Allocations__c> recordsToUpdate = new List<Program_Items_Facility_Allocations__c>();
    List<ASN_POS_Items_Users__c> asnPosItemUsersListUpdate = new List<ASN_POS_Items_Users__c>();
    Decimal totalRatio = 0;
    Decimal remainingQuantity = totalASNItemProcessed;
    for(Program_Items_Facility_Allocations__c programItemFacilityAllocation : programItemFacilityAllocationList)
    {
        totalRatio += programItemFacilityAllocation.Ratio__c;
    }
    if(programItemFacilityAllocationList.size() > 0)
    {
        System.debug('inside if');
        for(Program_Items_Facility_Allocations__c programItemFacilityAllocation : programItemFacilityAllocationList)
        {
            Decimal allocatedQuantity = (programItemFacilityAllocation.Ratio__c / totalRatio) * totalASNItemProcessed;
            allocatedQuantity = Math.round(allocatedQuantity);
            if (allocatedQuantity < remainingQuantity) 
            {
                programItemFacilityAllocation.Total_allocated_quantity__c += allocatedQuantity;
                programItemFacilityAllocation.Processing_Count__c += 1;
                recordsToUpdate.add(programItemFacilityAllocation);
                remainingQuantity -= allocatedQuantity;
            }
            else 
            {
                // If the allocated quantity is greater than or equal to the remaining quantity, update with the remaining quantity
                programItemFacilityAllocation.Total_allocated_quantity__c += remainingQuantity;
                programItemFacilityAllocation.Processing_Count__c += 1;
                recordsToUpdate.add(programItemFacilityAllocation);
                remainingQuantity = 0;
            }
            Processing_Date_and_Time__c processingDateObj = new Processing_Date_and_Time__c();
            processingDateObj.Program_Items_Facility_Allocations__c = programItemFacilityAllocation.Id;
            processingDateObj.Date_and_Time__c = DateTime.now();
            processingDateList.add(processingDateObj);
            //addAsnPosItemUser(programItemFacilityAllocation.User__c, asnPosItem.Id, posItemId, facilityId)
            ASN_POS_Items_Users__c asnPosItemUser = new ASN_POS_Items_Users__c();
            asnPosItemUser.User__c = programItemFacilityAllocation.User__c;
            asnPosItemUser.ASN_POS_Item__c = asnPosItem.Id;
            asnPosItemUser.Account__c = objAccount.Id;
            asnPosItemUser.POS_Item__c = posItemId;
            asnPosItemUser.Facility__c = facilityId;
            asnPosItemUser.Allocated_Stock__c = programItemFacilityAllocation.Total_allocated_quantity__c;
            asnPosItemUser.Active__c  = true;
            asnPosItemUsersListUpdate.add(asnPosItemUser);
                
        }
        if (!recordsToUpdate.isEmpty()) 
        {
            update recordsToUpdate;
        }

        if (!processingDateList.isEmpty()) 
        {
            insert processingDateList;
        }
        if(Test.isRunningTest())
        {
            System.debug('do nothing');  
        }
        else if(!asnPosItemUsersListUpdate.isEmpty())
        {
            insert asnPosItemUsersListUpdate;
        }  
            
    }
    updateProssedFlag();
}
```

I am getting an error when i try to insert asnPosItemUsersListUpdate

Why ?
Help to fix this please

The error msg i am getting is

> Error:Apex trigger ASNSeasonalAllocationTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ASNSeasonalAllocationTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, ASNSeasonalAllocationTrigger: maximum trigger depth exceeded ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate ASN_POS_Item trigger event AfterUpdate: []: Class.FetzerCalculateTotalAllocatedForAUser.calculateTotalAllocation: line 193, column 1

Comment: It seems like you have an infinite loop somewhere. The cause isn't immediately apparent (it's not in the code you've included), but an educated guess is that you either have a trigger on `ASN_POS_Items_Users__c` that causes an update to `ASN_POS_Item__c` or perhaps a rollup summary field on `ASN_POS_Item__c` (summarizing `ASN_POS_Items_Users__c`). In general, you should stick to having data flow in only one direction (e.g. from `ASN_POS_Items_Users__c` up to `ASN_POS_Item__c` and not the other way around`). Bidirectional data flows need extra consideration to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: Thank you @DerekF I have got the correct output. 
Thank you for your help